# adding an object to array- C++- Arduino

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

I feel like I am missing something simple here, I am writing some code for an Arduino, I did write the class myself but have not included the code for it, I don't think that is the issue since I can create the empty array and single object of the `player` class without any error, however when I try to add an object to the array it wont compile, error is included as comment in code, thanks.

```
char code[10];
void setup()
{
    //array of player objects
    player List[6];
}

void loop()
{
    //This line sets up a new 'player' and compiles without any issues
    player temp = player(code, 13);
    //The rest of the this short test code compiles fine, untill i add this line
    // and it gives an error as follows
    //  sketch_dec29a:20: error: 'List' was not declared in this scope 
    List[0] = temp;
```

Comment: `List` is a local variable to `setup()`. You need to declare it in an outer scope.

Comment: List no longer exists after the call to setup()

Answer (score 0):

`player List[6]` can't be accessed because it is a local variable in `setup()`.